# Improving performance (IEnumerable vs IQueryable) in my project

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using Telerik in ASP.NET MVC to display a grid that houses result data. We have a database of nearly 400k records, so I need to be sure my queries are performance friendly as possible.

I have the following `IEnumerable<Result> ReturnQuery` as shown here:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Result> ReturnQueryResults(TestDataViewModel obj, bool hasSearchFilter)
{
    var data = db.Results.AsQueryable();
    string ss = "";

    if (!hasSearchFilter)
    {
        data = data.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID).Take(100);
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.SiteLocation.ToString()))
    {
        var siteLocationName = db.SiteLocations.Where(x => x.ID == obj.SiteLocation).Select(x => x.SiteLocation1).FirstOrDefault();
        data = data.Where(x => x.SiteLocation == obj.SiteLocation);
        ss = ss + " Site Location: " + siteLocationName + ";";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.tempSetPoint))
    {
        data = data.Where(x => x.TempSetpoint == obj.tempSetPoint);
        ss = ss + " Temp Setpoint: " + obj.tempSetPoint + ";";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.unitSetPoint))
    {
        var uspLabel = GetUnitSetPointLabel();
        data = data.Where(x => x.UnitSetPoint == obj.unitSetPoint);
        ss = ss + " " + uspLabel + ": " + obj.unitSetPoint + ";";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.status))
    {
        data = data.Where(z => z.Status == obj.status);
        ss = ss + " Status: " + obj.status + ";";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.StartDate.ToString()))
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.EndDate.ToString()))
        {
            data = data.Where(z => obj.StartDate <= z.EndDate && obj.EndDate >= z.EndDate);
            ss = ss + " End Date between: " + Convert.ToDateTime(obj.StartDate).ToShortDateString() + " and " + Convert.ToDateTime(obj.EndDate).ToShortDateString() + ";";
        }
        else
        {
            data = data.Where(z => obj.StartDate <= z.EndDate);
            ss = ss + " End Date after: " + Convert.ToDateTime(obj.StartDate).ToShortDateString() + ";";
        }
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.TestNumber))
    {
        var noSpaces = obj.TestNumber.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        string[] testnumbers = noSpaces.Split(',');
        data = data.Where(z => testnumbers.Contains(z.TestNumber.ToString()));
        ss = ss + " Test Number: " + obj.TestNumber + ";";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.unitModel))
    {
        data = data.Where(z => z.UnitModel == obj.unitModel);
        ss = ss + " Model: " + obj.unitModel + ";";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.ProjectNum))
    {
        data = data.Where(z => z.ProjectNum == obj.ProjectNum);
        ss = ss + " Project: " + obj.ProjectNum + ";";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.testType))
    {
        data = data.Where(z => z.TestType == obj.testType);
        ss = ss + " TestType: " + obj.testType + ";";
    }    
        
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.testStall))
    {
        data = data.Where(z => z.Stall == obj.testStall);
        ss = ss + " Station: " + obj.testStall + ";";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.UnitID))
    {
        data = data.Where(z => z.UnitID == obj.UnitID);
        ss = ss + " Unit: " + obj.UnitID + ";";
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.testName))
    {
        data = data.Where(z => z.TestName.Contains(obj.testName));
        ss = ss + " Test Name: " + obj.testName + ";";
    }         

    if (ss == "")
    {
        ss = "No filter applied";
    }
    else
        ss = "Filters applied: " + ss;

    data = data.OrderBy(x => x.EndDate);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["TestDataQueryString"] = ss;

    return data;
}
```

The method above simply handles the view model (contains search parameters) and filters through the data.

The other method below, is my _Read method for the Telerik grid, where I populate my view model I use to display the Grid data.

```cs
public ActionResult _ReadResults([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var parameters = (TestDataViewModel)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["TestDataParams"];

    if (parameters == null)
    {
        parameters = new TestDataViewModel();
    }

    bool hasSearchFilter = parameters.GetType().GetProperties()
                    .Any(p => p.GetValue(parameters) != null);

    var data = ReturnQueryResults(parameters, hasSearchFilter);
    data = data.AsEnumerable();

    var list = data.Select(x => new ResultGridViewModel()
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        Status = x.Status,
        TestNumber = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TestNumber.ToString())) ? x.TestNumber.ToString() : "",
        RequestNum = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.RequestNum)) ? x.RequestNum : "",
        ProjectNum = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProjectNum)) ? x.ProjectNum : "",
        TempSetPoint = x.TempSetpoint,
        PDFLink = (x.PDFLink != null) ? x.PDFLink.ToString() : "x",
        TestType = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TestType)) ? x.TestType : "",
        TestName = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TestName)) ? x.TestName : "",
        Engineer = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Engineer)) ? x.Engineer : "",
        Tester = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Tester)) ? x.Tester : "",
        Stall = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Stall)) ? x.Stall: "",
        StartDate = x.TestDate,
        EndDate = x.EndDate,
        Duration = (x.TestDate != null && x.EndDate != null) ? (x.EndDate - x.TestDate).ToString() : "",
        UnitSerial = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.UnitSerial)) ? x.UnitSerial : "",
        UnitModel = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.UnitModel)) ? x.UnitModel : "",
        UnitID = (x.UnitID != null) ? x.UnitID : "",
        ResultFile = x.ResultFile,
        RedirectToUnit = x.UnitID,
        Comment1 = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Comment1)) ? x.Comment1 : "",
        Comment2 = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Comment2)) ? x.Comment2 : "",
        TesterComment = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TesterComment)) ? x.TesterComment : "",            
        TSLabel1 = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TSLabel1)) ? x.TSLabel1 : "",
        TSLabel2 = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TSLabel2)) ? x.TSLabel2 : "",
        TSLabel3 = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TSLabel3)) ? x.TSLabel3 : "",
        TSLabel4 = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TSLabel4)) ? x.TSLabel4 : "",
        TSValue1 = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TSValue1)) ? x.TSValue1 : "",
        TSValue2 = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TSValue2)) ? x.TSValue2 : "",
        TSValue3 = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TSValue3)) ? x.TSValue3 : "",
        TSValue4 = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TSValue4)) ? x.TSValue4 : "",
        RequirementNumber = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.RequirementNumber)) ? x.RequirementNumber : "",
        ProtocolID = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ProtocolNumber)) ? x.ProtocolNumber : "",
        TraceabilityMatrix = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TraceabilityMatrix)) ? x.TraceabilityMatrix : "",
        UnitSetPoint = x.UnitSetPoint,
        Charge1 = x.Charge1,
        Charge2 = x.Charge2,
        Charge22 = x.Charge22,
        SiteLocation = x.SiteLocation.ToString(),               
    });

    return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

You can see above where I call the first method from the second method.

```cs
var data = ReturnQueryResults(parameters, hasSearchFilter);
data = data.AsEnumerable();
```

The current reason I have the query as an `IEnumerable<>` is so that I can subtract dates and avoid an arithmetic error.

Would changing this method over to an `IQueryable<>` improve performance significantly?

My `ReturnQueryResults` is typed as an `IEnumerable` but I begin with

```cs
var data = db.Results.AsQueryable()
```

Does this still execute over the entire dataset?

Do you see any other further changes I could make to improve performance?

Thanks!

Comment: *Side question for anyone here: Since presumably, `db.Results` is a `DbSet<>` that already implements `IQueryable<>`, does anyone know if `db.Results.AsQueryable()` does anything except return the original `db.Results` reference? I'm just not sure why I keep seeing this in code.*

Comment: As far as I can see, the *dynamic type* of `data` remains an `IQueryable<>` throughout the code, althogh the *static type* changes to `IEnumerable<>` upon return from the `ReturnQueryResults()` call.  The `data = data.AsEnumerable();` does nothing, because the static type is already `IEnumerable<>`. (Its dynamic type remains `IQueryable<>`.) At the point where you apply `var list = data.Select(...);`, you are referencing the `IEnumerable<>.Select()`, which will execute a LINQ-to-Objects operation. The dynamic type becomes then becomes `IEnumerable<>`. ...

Comment: ... When the `JSON()` constructor is called, everything except the final `.Select()` logic will translate to a SQL query to be executed by the DBMS. The resulting rows are then mapped by the `.Select()` on the client side (client to SQL server, possibly a server to the user) and converted to JSON.

Comment: With this coding, I believe the database will return entire `Result` row objects (after applying all filters, order-by, and take opertions), because it does not see which columns are needed by the later `.Select()`. Potentially, some performance gain could be achieved by inserting another `.Select()` to just pick the needed columns prior to the static type change to `IEnumerable<>` (inside `ReturnQueryResults`), but this may be a negligible gain. I think what you have is close to optimal.

Comment: I would focus on reviewing the indexes on the SQL side needed to efficiently support all the various possible filter combinations and avoid table scans for the most common criteria.  Since the results are sorted by EndDate, indexes that start with or include that column should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsQueryable()` over `IQueryable` do nothing, think about this as just casting to `IQueryable<T>`

For example `data` in this snippet will have type `DbSet<Result>`

```cs
var data = db.Results;
```

After `AsQueryable()` it will be `IQueryable<Result>` and you can reuse this variable for query composing.

---

> `data = data.AsEnumerable();`
> Would changing this method over to an IQueryable<> improve performance significantly?

Not really, if you select almost all fields from `Result` table, performance will be almost the same.

---

> Do you see any other further changes I could make to improve performance?

I would remove this line

```cs
var siteLocationName = db.SiteLocations.Where(x => x.ID == obj.SiteLocation).Select(x => x.SiteLocation1).FirstOrDefault();
```

It will make additional call to database to retrieve name of location. If it is not critical, I would not use that.

Comment: We ran a tool that displayed our fully query at runtime. We are still somehow "executing" over the entire database. Do see how we could be doing this with the code above? Even when we search with a "Where" clause (picking a search parameter) it seems as if the entire dataset is first being queried causing a major slowdown. Any ideas?

Comment: You do not need tool to log EF Core queries. Debug step by step and analyse what has been executed. I do not see suspicious parts. Do you have enabled Lazy Loading?

Comment: I found an errant .Count() that was executing the result set on a separate method. This was the problem. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

It will make no difference. These 'As' methods aren't really doing anything to the result, they just make a var "look" different.

`Banana.AsFruit()` doesn't change the banana, it just means I can put it in the same bag as as my other fruits. I also can't `Peel()` a fruit like I could a banana, so once my banana is `AsFruit()` I lose that ability.

IQueryable (my banana) extends the IEnumerable (fruit) interface, so anything you can do with a "plain" IEnumerable (like eat it, or throw it), you can also do with an IQueryable but IQueryable has special specific methods (like Peel() in the banana example). If you don't need these extra methods you gain nothing from this interface.

Comment: We ran a tool that displayed our fully query at runtime. We are still somehow "executing" over the entire database. Do see how we could be doing this with the code above? Even when we search with a "Where" clause (picking a search parameter) it seems as if the entire dataset is first being queried causing a major slowdown. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I feel like `yeild` would help you.